# Firebase Firestore : Document is not mapping to Model class

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was trying to build an app using Firebase Firestore but after retrieving the data on `SnapshotListener` it is not mapping to my model.

Here is My `Model` class

```
public class BlogPost {
    private String description;
    private String image;
    private String user_id;
    private String thumbnail_url;
    private Timestamp timestamp;
    public BlogPost() {
    }
    public BlogPost(String description, String image, String user_id, String thumbnail_url, Timestamp  timestamp) {
        this.description = description;
        this.image = image;
        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.thumbnail_url = thumbnail_url;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUserId(String user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    public String getThumbnailUrl() {
        return thumbnail_url;
    }

    public void setThumbnailUrl(String thumbnail_url) {
        this.thumbnail_url = thumbnail_url;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Timestamp getPostTime() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setPostTime(Timestamp timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

}
```

To add data I am using this code:

```
firestore.collection("posts").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                for (DocumentChange doc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()){
                    if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){
                        BlogPost blogPost = doc.getDocument().toObject(BlogPost.class);

                        blogList.add(blogPost);`

                        blogRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Here is what I the object after mapping

> BlogPost{description='post 6', image='null', user_id='null', thumbnail_url='null', timestamp=null}

Here is database structure screenshot

[image: Database Structure]

As you can see description mapped but all other fields are null.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: We need to be able to see the actual document data you're working with, since Firestore will attempt to automatically map your document fields to your POJO properties using their names.  If the names of the fields don't match the names of the setter methods, the mapping will fail.

Comment: @DougStevenson  the database fields name are exact as variable in Model class.

Comment: Although I have added screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two changes need to be done.

-> Make Every data member in your data class public

-> Annotate them with @PropertName()

```
  public class BlogPost {

   @PropertyName("description")
   public String description;
   @PropertyName("image")
   public String image;
   @PropertyName("user_id")
   public String user_id;
   @PropertyName("thumbnail_url")
   public String thumbnail_url;
   @PropertyName("timestamp")
   public Timestamp timestamp;
  }
```

try this.

Comment: It's not necessarily the best decision to open up the members to be public.  From a design perspective, it's normally better to use the getter and setter methods, while leaving the members private.  This is all very possible to specify with Firestore.